# App getting crash while reloading the data

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

My `tableview` is getting reloaded and gets new data for every 10secs by running timer in background thread.But when data is getting reloaded and the same time when I'm scrolling the tableview .

App is getting crashed.leaving the error as

> [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 18 beyond bounds [0 .. 15].

Comment: I never understood why is it so difficult to provide code.

Comment: As error say's "index 18 beyond bounds [0 .. 15]" so simply your array is trying to fetch for object's which are not existing. So when you get new data you should initialise the array with it too before reloading the tableview. This way your array will have all object's it is looking for. Also agree with @nicael do provide code as it make's stuff clearer.

Comment: it clearly says the index you tried to access is `18` however the array has only `16` element. don't try to access to an object which does not exists, that would solve your problem in general.

Comment: @user3705826, are u able to figure out what was the issue is? Try to add some code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove objects from your array when you get the response. I guess you are removing your array first and then your timer is executing.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code, so this is a it of a guess, but as others have said it seems likely that you are reloading your data directly into the array that is your table data source. This is causing a timing related issue where your data source array and the information you have provided to the table view previously (specifically number of rows) is inconsistent.

You should fetch your new data into a different array and then once all data has been fetched you can update the reference to your table data source array and reload the table view.

Another approach is to compare the two arrays to determine which rows have been deleted and which rows are new. You can then call delete/insert rows as appropriate. Make sure you call beginUpdates before you start adding/deleting rows and endUpdates once you have finished.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to reload your table in main thread. Like below code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
          [self.collection reloadData];

            });
```